# Anylogic seize block Seize resources from resource pool if other resource pool is busy

Tags: java, conditional-statements, logic, anylogic

I am trying to simulate a supermarket and am trying to seize resources based on a condition.

I have an overall resource pool 'RP1' with workers and 3 types of categories.
I would like to create a logic with a new extra Resource pool 'RP2' designed to type 1, such that type 1 only uses that resource pool, however if it is fully occupied then it could use from 'RP1'.

Is this possible in anylogic?

I hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your `Seize` block to use alternative resource sets. If the first one cannot be used (your RP1), the agent will try to seize from RP2 instead, see below:
[image]

More details here: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/using-resources.html#using-resources

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly :-)  I have another question, is it possible to take the mean of aa dataset such that I can use that mean in the replication output?

What I want is to estimate the queue length from a bock during the process time. I have written QueueBlock.StatsSize.mean();  When I run the replication 10 times  I would like the mean of the queue length right now I only get the end queue length... Is that possible I can't get it to work.

Comment: Please ask new questions separately, StackOverflow works best this way :)

Comment: YEs I have asked separately now :-)